# Decrypt TLS encrypted messages signed by self-signed X509 Certificate based on Private Key generated from SECP521R1 curve

Tags: encryption, tls1.2, x509certificate, private-key, curve

How can i decrypt tcpdumped TLS encrypted messages, stored in DUMP.pcap file?
The messages were signed by self-signed `X509 Certificate` based on Private Key generated from `SECP521R1 curve`.

I have cert.pem, private_key.pem and private_key.der of this Certificate, also tcpdump file - DUMP.pcap

- **Wireshark**. I open DUMP.pcap file in `Wireshark`, then in Preferences -> Protocols -> TLS: RSA keys list - trying to add my private_key.pem and getting this error: `Can't load private key from ...private_key_file_path...: private key public key algorithm isn't RSA`.
- **Openssl**. Using command line tool `openssl` tried a lot of ways to decrypt it, from Google, from ChatGPT - nothing helped me.

I don't know and haven't found others tools that can do it.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help and suggestions

Comment: TLS data messages are never signed, only MAC'ed. In TLS1.2 and below (but not 1.3) a server using an RSA key/cert can (if the client agrees) use outdated RSA-only key-exchange, which can be decrypted using the server privatekey. A 1.2 server also can and usually does, and a 1.3 RSA server or **any server with ECDSA or EdDSDA key/cert _must_, use [FF|EC]DHE key-exchange, which cannot be decrypted** unless one of your endpoints exported e.g. logged the ephemeral secret(s) during the connection. This is intentional and is called [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy)

Comment: Many client/servers can put into a debug mode that logs these secrets to permit wireshark to decrypt TLS traffic. One of the more common ways can simply be called the `SSLKEYLOGFILE` method for the name of the environment variable involved. Use you search engine to look for this environment variable with the name of the TLS  peer/library you are using.